# What's the monad being used with =<< in this function?

Tags: haskell, monads

The **[very first](https://github.com/1HaskellADay/1HAD/tree/master/exercises/HAD/Y2014/M02)** 1-Haskell-a-Day exercise confuses me to a point of no return.
The objective is to filter out elements of a list unless it's equal to the one following. E.g.

```
> filterByPair [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[2,2,3]
```

(I was trying to make two offset lists, zip them into tuples and remove the tuples that didn't have the same number both times, e.g. [(2,2),(2,2),(3,3)], etc.)
But the mind-blowingly simple solution uses the `=<<` binding operator:

```
filterByPair :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
filterByPair = (init =<<) . group
```

I'm having trouble figuring that operator out. I don't get the same results in ghci when I try to use it:

```
> init =<< [2,3,4]
No instance for (Num [b0]) arising from the literal `2'
```

I find that in ghci I can use, say, `replicate` with `=<<`. It seems to be feeding each element of the list into the function:

```
> replicate 2 =<< [2,3,4]
[2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

So the first go-around is equivalent to:

```
> replicate 2 2
[2,2]
```

It somehow knows to put the list in the second argument of `replicate`, not the first, and to output them all in one big list rather than separate ones, like `fmap` does:

```
> fmap (replicate 2) [2,3,4]
[[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
```

I've read that the binding operator is defined by the monad being used. It's a monad function isn't it? Where's the monad with `filterByPair`? Does it have something to do with the `Eq` typeclass in its signature?

Likewise, if I use `=<<` on its own in ghci, what monad is being used there?

Comment: `group` has type `Eq a => [a]->[[a]]`. Perhaps the fact that `[2,3,4]` does not quite mach `[[a]]` has something to do with the type error you are experiencing. What if you try something that is in fact a list of lists instead?

Comment: This one is explained on the wiki: https://github.com/1HaskellADay/1HAD/wiki/2014-02-24-filterByPair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `filterPairs` rewritten into pointful form for clarity:

```
filterPairs xs = group xs >>= init
```

We'll be able to get a good idea what's happening from the types alone.

```
xs    :: Eq a => [a]
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
init  :: [a] -> [a]

(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The first argument to `(>>=)` is `group xs :: [[s]]`, so if we substitute `m ~ []` and `a ~ [s]` in `(>>=)` we'll get

```
(>>=) :: [[a]] -> ([a] -> [s]) -> [s]
```

So we're using the `Monad` instance of `[]` here, which is equivalent to `concatMap` (check the types!). Now we can rewrite `filterPairs` again

```
filterPairs xs = concatMap init (group xs)
```

Now if you figure out how `concatMap`, `init` and `group` work, you should be able to figure how the original `filterPairs` works.

Comment: Thanks for this. Question: you say in list monad, bind is equivalent to concatMap. How does one know this? Is it documented anywhere in Hackage?

Comment: Note that `concatMap` is only equivalent to `(=<<)` when the monadic type is "List".
When using concatMap (and more generally lists), if you try to make it more "type generic", you will want to substitute `[] ~ m` and fall back on bind.